# two PHP loops in one html div

Tags: php, html

I have below code for help contents,

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <?php
  foreach($helpCategoryArray as $category)
  {
  ?>
     <div id="tab_<?php echo $category["helpcategory_id"]?>" class="tab-pane active">
    <div id="accordion1" class="panel-group">
        <?php
        foreach($topicsArray as $topic)
        {
        ?>

        <div class="panel panel-default" id="topic_<?php echo $topic["topic_id"]?>">
            <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#accordion1_1">
            <?php echo $topic["topic_subject"]?>
            </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="accordion1_1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
            <div class="panel-body" id="context" data-toggle="context" data-target="#context-menu">
            <?php echo $topic["topic_content"]?>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        }                                       
        ?>                          
        </div>
        </div>                  
        <?php
        }               
        ?>  
</div>
```

What is my requirement is left side of page is tree of selection, when one item category is selected, related contents are loading on right side,

Now on above code  have did that with id=tab_x, x will come from DB, so need loop for that, so that i can give reference to tab_x as href,

In tab div, i have help topics which are related to this items, so i need to loop all my topics here,

Problem is that my one help topic is also looping in first loop looping times,

So how to echo this help topic,

Thanks,

Comment: can you please edit your question to include the html code you expect to have?

Comment: @AlexAndrei, this is my html code only, but i have issue with this, that echo of variable loops as per first loop goes on

Comment: please post the contents of the two arrays `$helpCategoryArray` and `$topicsArray`

Comment: I don't think you should be nesting your loops. You should have two separate loops, one for the left DIV, another one for the right DIV.

Comment: now all the categories are looped and all the topics are looped for all categories. how both arrays are related?

Comment: @AlexAndrei, $helpCategoryArray produce just numbers which i used for tab_X is, where X  = 1,3,4, etc. with this i will create tabs and now in each tab i will have $topicsArray contents, means subject and content, if there are 3 topic, then this will repeat 3 time, and if there are 5 topic then tab-1,2,3,4,5 .

Answer (score 0):

Finally it solved with adding If condition in first PHP loop,

```
if ($category["helpcategory_id"] == $topic["topic_category"])
    {--code---}
```